# printing strings and referenced variables before assignment

Tags: python

I have a programming asking the user to choose out of 10 questions, which one they want answered. For questions 2, 4, and 7 they also have the option to choose between displaying them in metric or american format. I was able to convert them fine, but the output is displaying unwanted parentheses and commas, and ever since I introduced the converted answers, I can't display the other questions if they are selected.

program---

```
def main():

   print("Hello, here you can choose from these questions, and we'll answer them!")
   q1 = "How many plastic water bottles do Americans throw away a second?"
   q2 = "How much food do Americans throw in the trash every year?"
   q3 = "How many people could be fed with 5 percent of that wasted food?"
   q4 = "How much waste does the entire U.S. economy create to make a year's worth of food, fuel, resource extraction and products for one American?"
   q5 = "How much of that total waste figure is recycled?"
   q6 = "How much energy is wasted on junk mail?"
   q7 = "How many liters of water are needed to make one liter of bottled water?"
   q8 = "How much disposable plastic wrap is made each year in America?"  
   q9 = "How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?"
   q10 = "How much plastic trash ends up in the ocean?"

   ans1 = "694"
   ans2 = "96 billion pounds"
   ans3 = "4 million for a year"
   ans4 = "Just under 1 million pounds (waste water not included)"
   ans5 = "2 percent"
   ans6 =  "One day's worth could heat 250,000 homes."
   ans7 = "3 liters"
   ans8 = "Enough to shrink-wrap Texas" 
   ans9 = "25 billion, or enough cups to circle the earth 436 times"
   ans10 =  "The United Nations estimates there are about 46,000 pieces of plastic trash per square mile of ocean, and that 5.6 million tons of trash are dumped, blown or washed into the seven seas."
   question, answer, choice = getchoice()

   print(question)
   print(answer)
   newanswer = getunits(choice)
   print(newanswer)



def getchoice():
   print("The questions are:  \n1. How many plastic water bottles do Americans throw away a second?\n2. How much food do Americans throw in the trash every year?\n3. How many people could be fed with 5 percent of that wasted food?\n4. How much waste does the entire U.S. economy create to makea year's worth of food, fuel, resource extraction and products for one American?\n5. How much of that total waste figure is recycled?\n6. How much energy is wasted on junk mail?\n7. How many liters of water are needed to make one liter of bottled water?\n8. How much disposable plastic wrap is made each year in America?\n9. How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?\n10. How much plastic trash ends up in the ocean?")
   choice = input("Which question would you like the answer for? (type in '1' or '2'..etc): ")
   while choice != "1" and choice != "2" and choice != "3" and choice != "4" and choice != "5" and choice != "6" and choice != "7" and choice != "8" and choice!= "9" and choice != "10":   
      choice = input("Which question would you like the answer for? (type in '1' or '2'..etc): ")
   if choice == "1":
      question = "How many plastic water bottles do Americans throw away a second?"
      answer = "694"

   elif choice == "2":
      question = "How much food do Americans throw in the trash every year?"
      answer = ""
   elif choice == "3":
      question = "How many people could be fed with 5 percent of that wasted food?"
      answer = "4 million for a year."
   elif choice == "4":
      question = "How much waste does the entire U.S. economy create to make a year's worth of food, fuel, resource extraction and products for one American?"
      answer = ""
   elif choice == "5":
      question = "How much of that total waste figure is recycled?"
      answer = "2 percent"
   elif choice == "6":
      question = "How much energy is wasted on junk mail"  
      answer = "One day's worth could heat 250,000 homes."
   elif choice == "7":
      question = "How many liters of water are needed to make one liter of bottled water?"
      answer = ""
   elif choice == "8":
      question = "How much disposable plastic wrap is made each year in America?"
      answer = "Enough to shrink-wrap Texas"
   elif choice == "9":
      question = "How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?"
      answer = "25 billion, or enough cups to circle the earth 436 times"
   elif choice == "10":
      question = "How much plastic trash ends up in the ocean?"
      answer = "The United Nations estimates there are about 46,000 pieces of plastic trash per square mile of ocean, and that 5.6 million tons of trash are dumped, blown or washed into the seven seas."

   return question, answer, choice



def getunits(choice):
   units = input("Do you want units in Metric or American format? (enter 'm' or 'a') ")
   if units == "m":
      if choice == "2":
         conversion = str(96000000000 * .453592)
         newanswer = (conversion,"Kilograms")
      if choice == "4":
         conversion = str(1000000 * .45392)
         newanswer = (conversion,"Kilograms")
      if choice == "7":
         conversion = str(3 * .26)
         newanswer = (conversion,"gallons!")       

   return newanswer



main()
```

output---

```
Hello, here you can choose from these questions, and we'll answer them!
The questions are:  
1. How many plastic water bottles do Americans throw away a second?
2. How much food do Americans throw in the trash every year?
3. How many people could be fed with 5 percent of that wasted food?
4. How much waste does the entire U.S. economy create to makea year's worth of food, fuel, resource extraction and products for one American?
5. How much of that total waste figure is recycled?
6. How much energy is wasted on junk mail?
7. How many liters of water are needed to make one liter of bottled water?
8. How much disposable plastic wrap is made each year in America?
9. How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?
10. How much plastic trash ends up in the ocean?
Which question would you like the answer for? (type in '1' or '2'..etc): 2
How much food do Americans throw in the trash every year?

Do you want units in Metric or American format? (enter 'm' or 'a') m
('43544832000.0', 'Kilograms')
```

---

```
Hello, here you can choose from these questions, and we'll answer them!
The questions are:  
1. How many plastic water bottles do Americans throw away a second?
2. How much food do Americans throw in the trash every year?
3. How many people could be fed with 5 percent of that wasted food?
4. How much waste does the entire U.S. economy create to makea year's worth of food, fuel, resource extraction and products for one American?
5. How much of that total waste figure is recycled?
6. How much energy is wasted on junk mail?
7. How many liters of water are needed to make one liter of bottled water?
8. How much disposable plastic wrap is made each year in America?
9. How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?
10. How much plastic trash ends up in the ocean?
Which question would you like the answer for? (type in '1' or '2'..etc): 9
How many nonrecyclable Styrofoam cups do Americans throw away in a year?
25 billion, or enough cups to circle the earth 436 times
Do you want units in Metric or American format? (enter 'm' or 'a') a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment6b.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "assignment6b.py", line 36, in main
    newanswer = getunits(choice)
  File "assignment6b.py", line 95, in getunits
    return newanswer
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'newanswer' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getunits(choice):
    newanswer =''
    conversion = ''
```

add a `newanswer` in you getunits function, it will local to getunits scope

```
def getchoice():
    question = ''
    answer = ''
```

demo:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def test():
...     x += 1
... 
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
UnbondLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>> def test():
...     x = 0
...     print x+1
... 
>>> test()
1
>>> x
10
>>>
```

The error is raise because x is local to function, it doesn't know about `x = 10`

so whatever you define inside a function, its under the scope of function

you can replace this:

```
while choice != "1" and choice != "2" and choice != "3" and choice != "4" and choice != "5" and choice != "6" and choice != "7" and choice != "8" and choice!= "9" and choice != "10":
```

to:

```
while choice not in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]:
```

Comment: hope this might help you

Comment: I'm now having trouble on being able to display the answers for 2,4 and 7 used in the get units function

Comment: @Johnwayne you also need to declare `conversion` in getunits function